# Connectionstring to other projects' App_Data folder

Tags: asp.net, web-config, connection-string, multiple-projects

I have a asp.net webforms project with a database in the App_Data folder referenced by connectionstring:

```
<add name="databaseconnectionstring" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|database.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The solution also contains another project with webservices that need to access the same database. 
**Is it possible to write a relative path to this database in the connnectionstring?** - eg. something like this(does not work):

```
<add name="databaseconnectionstring" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|/../../ProjectName/App_Data/database.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically `|DataDirectory|` is an alias for `App_Data` folder. Since you are not using `App_Data` in your services project, it would not help you in this situation.

What you can do though is try starting from the project root using `~\`:

```
AttachDbFilename=~\..\ProjectName\App_Data\database.mdf
```

Also there is always an option to use an absolute path:

```
AttachDbFilename=d:\Projects\ProjectName\App_Data\database.mdf
```

And finally there is always an option to build connection string programmatically.

Comment: It didn't work.. But I think that if that doesn't work, it is properly not possible without an absolut path..

Comment: @MortenHolmgaard, most likely you are right - it was just a wild guess. However maybe you can opt to build connection string at runtime.

Comment: It might be possible - but it is not a critical feature so I will just go with the absolut path.

Comment: @MortenHolmgaard, than I'll add absolute path option to the post - just for the sake of completeness.